# using sql concat through SQLAlchemy duplicates value

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have stored procedure which I call using SQLAlchemy that concatenates a column in MSSQL. When I run the same stored procedure through MSSQL, it behaves correctly but running through SQLAlchemy it duplicates the value.

stored procedure:

```
UPDATE table
SET LocationId = @LocationId,
BoxesDelivered = @BoxesDelivered,
TrackingNo = @BatchNumber,
From = CONCAT(From, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), @Info)
WHERE JobCode = @JobCode;
```

Here is the SQLAlchemy code:

```
 update_location = "EXEC UpdateCallerLocation "\
     "@JobCode=:job_code, "\
     "@LocationId=:new_location_id, "\
     "@BoxesDelivered=:boxes_delivered, "\
     "@BatchNumber=:batch_number, "\
     "@Info=:batch_info"
```

Running this via SQLAlchemy and I get the following:

```
order delivered on: 01-11-2023    
order delivered on: 11-11-2023
order delivered on: 11-11-2023
```

the last 2 entries are duplicated executing the stored procedure once through SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Ensure you are not creating a new session unintentionally for each call.

Comment: Thanks, exactly as you said. I had unintentionally created a new session